# How to migrate from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer to Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer in .net 8?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Below code was implemented by Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer package; however, it is deprecated.
and I would like to upgrade this code to .NET 8 using the alternate package Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Catalog.API.Controllers;

[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
//[Authorize(Policy = "CanRead")]
public class ApiController: ControllerBase
{   
}
```

I installed Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer 7.1.0 on .net 8.0.
However, I got below error.
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ApiVersionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ApiVersion' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer;  // this prompts Mvc is missing in the Asp.Versioning.

namespace Catalog.API.Controllers;

[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
//[Authorize(Policy = "CanRead")]
public class ApiController: ControllerBase
{   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Asp.Versioning;
// Working with ASP.NET Core, you should use the Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer package.
// The Asp.Versioning.WebApi.ApiExplorer package is intended for use with the legacy ASP.NET Web API platform.

namespace Catalog.API.Controllers;

[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
//[Authorize(Policy = "CanRead")]
public class ApiController: ControllerBase
{
    
}
```

simply using Asp.Versioning;